# Scala.js event handling

Tags: scala, event-handling, scala.js

I'm writing a little Scala.Js app that uses two event handlers: one for an input field's `onkeyup` event and another for a button's `onclick` event.

The two event handlers share quite a bit of common coding, but as soon as I try to optimise the event handler coding into a single function that returns an event handler function, it compiles correctly, but events are no longer trapped in the browser.

In the following code in function `main`, the event handler for `btn.onclick` works fine, but the event handler for `cityNameInput.onkeyup` no longer works.  All I did was copy the coding assigned directly to the event handler, and put it in a function called `keystrokeHandler` that returns a `Function1[dom.Event, _]`.  This compiles OK, but the `onkeyup` event is no longer trapped in the browser.

```scala
def keystrokeHandler(userInput: String, responseDiv: dom.Element): Function1[dom.Event,_] =
(e: dom.Event) => {
  // The city name must be at least 4 characters long
  if (userInput.length > 3) {
    responseDiv.innerHTML = ""

    val xhr = buildXhrRequest(userInput, searchEndpoint)

    xhr.onload = (e: dom.Event) => {
      val data: js.Dynamic = js.JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)

      // Can any cities be found?
      if (data.count == 0)
      // Nope, so show error message
        responseDiv.appendChild(p(s"Cannot find any city names starting with ${userInput}").render)
      else {
        // Build a list of weather reports
        buildSearchList(data, responseDiv)
      }
    }

    // Send XHR request to OpenWeather
    xhr.send()
  }
}
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// Main program
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
@JSExport
def main(container: dom.html.Div): Unit = {
  container.innerHTML = ""

  val cityNameInput = input.render
  val btn           = button.render
  val weatherDiv    = div.render

  cityNameInput.defaultValue = owmQueryParams.get("q").get
  btn.textContent            = "Go"

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // Button onclick event handler
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  btn.onclick = (e: dom.Event) => {
    if (cityNameInput.value.length > 3) {
      weatherDiv.innerHTML = ""

      val xhr = buildXhrRequest(cityNameInput.value, weatherEndpoint)

      xhr.onload = (e: dom.Event) => {
        val data = js.JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)

        // Can the city be found?
        if (data.cod == "404")
        // Nope, so show error message
          weatherDiv.appendChild(p(s"City ${cityNameInput.value} not found").render)
        else {
          // So first add the div containing both the weather information
          // and the empty div that will hold the slippy map.
          // This is needed because Leaflet writes the map information to an
          // existing DOM element
          val report = new WeatherReportBuilder(data)
          weatherDiv.appendChild(buildWeatherReport(report, 0))

          buildSlippyMap("mapDiv0", report)
        }
      }

      // Send XHR request to OpenWeather
      xhr.send()
    }
  }

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // Input field onkeyup event handler
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  cityNameInput.onkeyup = keystrokeHandler(cityNameInput.value, weatherDiv)

  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  // Write HTML to the screen
  // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  container.appendChild(
    div(
      h1("Weather Report"),
      table(
        tr(td("Enter a city name (min 4 characters)"), td(cityNameInput)),
        tr(td(), td(style := "text-align: right", btn))
      ),
      weatherDiv
    ).render
  )
}
```

What's the problem here?

Should the `keystrokeHandler` function return some special Scala.Js event handler type?  Or is it something else?

Thanks

Chris W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
cityNameInput.onkeyup = keystrokeHandler(cityNameInput.value, weatherDiv)
```

The event handler *is* triggered, but the `userInput` is frozen to `cityNameInput.value` *at the time the handler was created*, instead of varying with the current value of `cityNameInput.value`. Indeed, that line is equivalent to

```
val userInput = cityNameInput.value
cityNameInput.onkeyup = keystrokeHandler(userInput, weatherDiv)
```

which makes it obvious that `cityNameInput.value` is only evaluated once.

Instead, you should give `cityNameInput` itself as parameter to `keystrokeHandler`, and access `cityNameInput.value` inside the anonymous function, so that it is evaluated every time the function (handler) is called.

Comment: Ah, that's it.  Thanks